# KDE Plasma 5 Undesireable Keyboard Layout Switching Behavior

Tags: keyboard, kde, language-support, plasma

I recently switched OS from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu Studio 20.10 via a clean install. Overall, I am very happy with my new OS so far; Plasma is sleek and intuitive. However, I've been facing an annoying problem with the keyboard layouts that I have not quite been able to figure out.

During installation, I set the default language and keyboard layout to English (US). I've since added Spanish (Latin America) as an alternative layout with the Alt + Shift hotkey combination to switch between layouts, as in the screenshot below

[image]

So what's the problem? Well, layout switching only works for a single input entry. This means that the keyboard layout switches back to default whenever I click away from an input field. As long as I don't click away, the keyboard switch remains in Spanish. However, this automatic layout switching is incredibly annoying and renders instant messaging nearly unusable.

I've tried tinkering with the "Switching Policy" options with no change in seen behavior. Ideally, the right setting I want is for the keyboard layout to switch globally after the hotkey combination and to remain in that layout ***until*** the hotkey combination is pressed again. So, just like in GNOME.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have checked all Switching policy options. I have EurKEY and Greek selected with the Switching Policy on Global on KUbuntu 20.10 and the behavior is the one you describe for Gnome.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
Yeah, I'm pretty sure. I've experimented with a number of combinations to no avail.

Comment: Hi, @starseed_trooper. I had some strange problems with KDE layout switching these days, and I found your question. As I see, in my case it turned out that you have to add language support before adding corresponded keyboard layout. ([https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Change_Plasma_Language](https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Change_Plasma_Language))

Answer (score 1):

Adding the french canadian keyboard lead to the same annoying behavior for me. I even tried to delete the implicit US keyboard layout but saw no difference.

But it looks OK now that I added back the US layout and clicked the "spare layouts" box.
So far so good, I keep you posted if anything ...

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution helped me. Delete **~/.config/kxkbrc** file and reboot. Add other layouts via GUI, open **~/.config/kxkbrc**, remove all unnecessary lines, and make the configuration like here:

```
[Layout]
DisplayNames=,,
LayoutList=us,ru,il
Options=grp:alt_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
ResetOldOptions=false
SwitchMode=Global
Use=true
VariantList=,,lyx
```

Comment: Ended up here having the same problem...I noticed that `SwitchMode=Global` is not written to the kxkbrc when selected in the UI, while the other options are. But even after I manually change it to these settings, it still randomly switches layouts occasionally when I change between windows.